# Div margin: auto not centering page in Chrome, IE

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, alignment, margin

i'm running some basic beginner tutorials in order to learn how to properly run html. I've come to the portion where i'm using a div tag in css to center the content. However, once i open the test page, everything stays locked to the right of the browser. I've been scouring the forums for any solution and nothing seems to fix the issue. Tested in Chrome and IE.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>My First Website</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head> 
<body>

<div>
    <h1> My Website </h1>
    <p><a href="about/about.html">Learn more about me.</a></p>

    <img src="img/lady.jpg" alt="skyrim">


    <h2>My New Section </h2>

</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
    a {
    color: red; 
    text-decoration: none;  
}

h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
 }

div {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
     }
```

Comment: Are you missing a closing curly brace on the `div` rule or is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine in my end:

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/JH7NK/

If you mean that extra space you have vertically on top its your h1.

I edited to show you:

```
div h1 {margin: 0}
```

Comment: i ran that edit and it's still locked up. I'm starting to think its something to do with Chrome. Strange as everything seems to be up to date. Thanks for checking that out, i suppose i'll just have to suck it up and deal with it :( haha

Answer (score 3):

You have no Doctype. This puts you in [Quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) (the land of incompatibility).

Add one as the very first thing in your document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I've tried this and it still doesn't work :/ it pushes the page down only slightly and keeps everything to the left.

Comment: Make sure you're closing your `div` CSS properly, you're missing the last `}`

Comment: @RobertJRodriguez — Then, assuming that the missing `}` is a copy/paste failure (if it isn't [use a validator!](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)), I can't reproduce your problem: http://jsbin.com/opufom/1/edit

Comment: the missing } was indeed a copy/paste error haha still at a loss for what's happening.

Comment: also, so far as i've been working on this i've mostly used Chrome to test the page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `DOCTYPE`. This is an example of the `HTML5 DOCTYPE`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


        HTML here


</body>
</html>
```